# Why is the CursorQuery.java missing from GreenDAO?

Tags: android, orm, greendao

Looking at the source I found something I really need - a way to get a cursor from GreenDao. The missing class is called CursorQuery.java - and it does just what I need.

Now why isn't this in any of the available .jar files on mavencentral ?

Should I just copy the files to my project or what is the general idea with this class ?

Comment: ahhhh - I guess I'm just to

Comment: Ah - I guess I'm just too fast for my own good. It's scheduled for the next 2.1 release!!

Comment: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/commits?author=greenrobot